# Deleted object would be re-saved in many-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using the [Grails wiki example](https://grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML) to setup a many-to-many relationship. When I make the Membership.unlink(employee, team) call, the m.delete causes the "Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade" error and I can't seem to get around this.

Comment: the linked article relates to version 1.0.3 of grails (and is five years old by the way). Is this really the version you are working with? If not, have a look at the [current docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany) (v. 2.4.x) about GORM - perhaps this just answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an instance that is linked to a `hasMany` relationship, you also have to remove the object from the 'many' side. For example:

```
employee.removeFromTeam(team)
employee.delete(flush: true)
```

It looks like in your example, you likely have a `Membership` class which holds a `Team` and an `Employee` relationship. In this case, you'll need to do the following:

```
membership.removeFromTeam(team)
membership.removeFromEmployee(employee)
membership.delete(flush: true)
```